# Can't access NTFS drives after Elementary OS install

Tags: partition, ntfs, elementary-os, gparted

I have just setup Elementary OS.  I have two hard drives on my desktop and I can’t access either one of them via file manager. To be precise I have two partitions with data that I need to access;  dev/sda4(on a 160GB hard drive) and dev/sdb1(on a 1 TB hard drive).  I can see these drives using disk utility and gparted and they show them as unknown drives.

I have searched the internet for this problem and can’t seem to get anywhere.  I have found that I may need to run the command “sudo blkid” to find the device UID so I can mount them with fstab. But whenever I run "sudo blkid" , I just get the UIDs of the ext4 partion(where I installed elementary) and the swap partition.  I really need to access the data on those NTFS partitions. Is there any way I can mount those drives on Elementary?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have some packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs ntfs-config
```

If you do have those and it still isn't working, try this as well:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know NTFS-read&write is standard installed/enabled on most Ubuntu versions nowadays. For linux-n00bs (like myself) this worked perfectly: [How to Mount Partitions Automatically on Start Up in Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/mount-partitions-automatically-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We recommend that users summarise links they post in their answers in order to avoid situations where a link becomes stale (e.g. the website it points to gets closed) and the answer is therefore rendered useless. If you include a summary in your post the answer may still be helpful even if the link is not valid any more.